# PSQL Apply mapping to an array

Tags: postgresql

I have an array of an enum type `order_options` that gets passed through to a function and it is pretty simple, it looks like this:

```
'{master_date, e_name}'
```

I have 6 possible values and the enum type looks like this:

```
create type order_options as enum ('master_date','e_name','r_data','n_count','creation_date','last_updated_on');
```

In the function however, I want to apply a mapping to these values to change the value of `sort_params` which is the array passed through.

For each enum, I have an 'alternative name' that I want to use in the order by clause of a subsequent `select` statement. For example:

```
'master_date' = o.master_date
'e_name' = d.e_name
```

and so on.

I've looked in to doing a replace whereby I loop through each element of the array and attempt a replace with each mapping but it gets pretty messy and complex.

So for example, this works for one individual mapping:

```
select array_replace('{master_date}'::text[],'master_date','o.master_date');
```

I'd like my `sort_params` to look like this after mapping:

```
'{o.master_date, d.e_name}'
```

Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For now, this is what I have:

```
select array_replace(sort_params_u,'master_date','o.master_date') into sort_params_u;
select array_replace(sort_params_u,'e_name','d.e_name') into sort_params_u;
etc
```